# Selecting text in profile activity comments causes unexpected clipping

Tags: bug, comments, profile-page, design

This is a very minor bug I know, but in anyone's profile page, on the `Activity` or `Responses` tab, text highlighting is messed up for the `Comment` and `All` subcategories. This only seems to happen only in Chrome. I am on Version 31.0.1650.63 (Win 7). It is visibly worse on multiple lines of text.

[image: Weird highlighting]

Steps to repro:

1. Go to any profile on any Stack Exchange site, and click on Activity tab.
2. Go to `All` or `Comment` subcategories.
3. Highlight text.

As a side effect, you can even temporarily dismember the head of all those poor characters. To do this, start from any line, drag mouse left or right, drag up and then back down.

[image: Side effect]

I've bumped into bugs before that turned out to be Chrome problems, so maybe this is just Chrome doing its magic.

Comment: This is due to the `padding-bottom: 10px` on `.comments`. Not entirely sure why Chrome is using that to determine the highlight dimensions, but it doesn't look like just changing the CSS to work around it would hurt either.

Comment: Probably [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313593) (the test case there just works in the opposite direction, causing the selection area to shrink instead of expand).

Comment: Yeah that looks like the same issue, their test case works fine in FF too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `comments` class is used in two places: in the normal question view, it's applied to a `<div>` surrounding all the comments on a post, while in the profile activity / responses view it's applied to a `<span>` surrounding each individual comment.

Given that [top/bottom padding on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401140/padding-the-top-and-the-bottom-of-inline-element) like `<span>` has no (normally) visible effect, adding a CSS rule like:

```css
span.comments { padding-bottom: 0 }
```

ought to be a safe and easy way to work around this bug.

(Ps. This fix is now included in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14.)

Comment: Great, never heard/seen SOUP before, I'll give it a try sometime.